# pass a shared_ptr with "this" as a parameter and store it in a variable

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I want to pass a reference of an object of MyClass with "this", calling a method of another class.

This is how MyClass is defined

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<class MyClass> MyClassRef;

class MyClass {
  //bla bla bla
};

MyClass::method(){
  someObject->someMethod(this); //this object is from the ReceiverClass
}
```

I my main App I create the object this way:

```
myObject = MyClassRef( new MyClass());
```

So how must I define someMethod() in ReceiverClass to receive "this" as a param and then store it in a member variable??

In pseudo code I think it would be something like this...

```
class ReceiverClass {
  public:
    void someMethod(shared_ptr param);
    shared_ptr mReference;
};

ReceiverClass::someMethod(shared_ptr param){
    mReference = param;
}
```

... but I'm completely lost.

Comment: boost::enable_shared_from_this.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ethan Steinberg hinted at, have MyClass inherit from boost::enable_shared_from_this (or the std::tr1 or std version depending on what is available with your compiler). Then call your method as someObject->someMethod(shared_from_this()).

The idea is that shared_from_this() returns a shared_ptr to the calling object which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: MyClass is already inhering from some other class. (I know, not in the example)

Comment: @Pier: in C++, you can inherit from more base classes.